# LRU cache strangeness

Tags: python, hash

I'm encountering some behaviour which I can't explain.

I have some expensive functions that get called repeatedly; I have decorated them with `@lru_cache(None)` to help speed things up. My run times were still quite slow after doing that so I was a little confused.

I then realised that some of these functions had custom objects as parameters. My understanding is that by default, the hash for any custom object is based on it's ID. So my theory was that some of these expensive functions were being re-evaluated despite these arguments containing identical data. My objects are only used to group immutable data so I'm comfortable with looking up the cached value where the data within those objects is the same.

So based on my understanding of the `lru_cache` function, I added a `__hash__` method to my objects, just doing something very crude for starters:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(str(self.__dict__))
```

So my theory is that my program should now be much quicker, as the caching will now take place on some of these expensive functions where it wasn't before.

To my dismay, my program is vastly slower; possibly it's getting stuck somewhere as I have not even had the patience to let it finish. For context, without the custom `__hash__` methods a test case ran in about 16s; after adding the `__hash__` methods the same test case was still running after about 10 minutes.

I don't have a deep understanding of how `lru_cache` works, but I have had a look at the source code and as far as I can tell it will just use my `__hash__` function when it encounters those objects as parameters. Based on the drastic increase in run time, my current theory is that this is somehow causing the program to get stuck somewhere, rather than the cache lookups actually taking that long for some reason. But I can't see any reason why that would happen.

This feels like a bit of a wild goose chase to me but I can't imagine I'm the first person to try this. Does anybody know why this might happen?

Thanks

**Edit:**

I ran an even smaller test case to check if the program is actually terminating; it is. The smaller test case took 2.5s to run without the custom `__hash__` functions, and 40s with them.

I have to stress that nothing else is changing between these two runs. The only difference is that I am adding the `__hash__` function described above to three classes which take a journey around my code. Therefore I think the only possible conclusion is that my `__hash__` function is somehow hugely slower than the default that would otherwise be used by `lru_cache`. That is, unless implementing a custom `__hash__` function has other (invisible) costs that I'm not aware of.

I'm still at a loss to explain this. These are quite large objects which contain a lot of data, so `str(self.__dict__)` will be a pretty long string (probably thousands of characters). However I don't believe that hashing should take appreciably longer for a longer string. Perhaps Python does huge amounts of hashing in the background in various places and this small difference can add up? It seems far-fetched to me but there don't seem to be many options - the only alternative I can see is some weird interaction with the `lru_cache` logic which leads to a big slow-down. I'll keep doing experiments but hopefully someone will know the answer!

**Edit 2:**

I followed Samwise's suggestion and benchmarked this `__hash__` function and it does seem to be genuinely a lot slower, and given the number of calls I can believe that this is the entire reason for my issue. I'm guessing that the `self.__dict__` part is the bottleneck but my intuition about this doesn't have the best track-record so far.

That still leaves me with the problem of trying to speed up my code, but at least I know what's going on now.

**Edit 3:**

For anyone else who encounters this problem in the future - I decided to just pre-compute a hash value in my initialiser for my objects and return that in my `__hash__` function, and that has sped things up massively. This solution does depend on the object not being mutated after creation.

Comment: Can you give us an example? It's going to be hard to give more than general advice without having a test case

Comment: I'm not sure what more I can say other than drowning the question in code which I suspect to be irrelevant; but I'm happy to expand if you think there is something missing that will help answer the question. In summary I do not believe that my run times can expand that much by changing my expensive functions into lookups; so either I'm wrong in that assumption or there is a fundamental issue with my solution (adding the `__hash__` function).

Comment: Have you tried just benchmarking the `__hash__` function on its own?  How long does one invocation take (vs the default implementation) and how many times does it get called in a single invocation of your expensive function?

Comment: Hey @Samwise, I tried your suggestion and I think that's answered my question. If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @user6282181 - would you be able to share your "findings" - maybe it's worthy to publish to help others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question ended up being quite simple - `str(self.__dict__)` is actually a pretty slow thing to run on every function call. I'm not sure why I didn't think of that in the first place.

Ultimately what I decided to do was just add a property to my classes, _hash, and I would set this equal to `str(self.__dict__)` at the end of initialising a new object. Then in my custom `__hash__` method I would just grab the value of _hash, so that now `lru_cache` will work for functions with arguments which assume the type of my objects and not have to call `str(self.__dict__)` for every function call.

I should make it clear that this only works under the assumption that the object has its entire state defined at initialisation and doesn't get mutated over its lifetime - if it does, then the hash will go out of date you'll end up getting hits from the cache that aren't appropriate.

Comment: Hashable Python objects are not supposed to be mutated in ways that would affect hashing or equality in general, whether or not they cache their hashes. This isn't like, say, Java, where everything is supposed to be hashable regardless of mutation or mutability.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. I am assuming that Python would normally not allow you to do to do something that will change a hash value - is that right? In my case I have to just remember and be careful not to do something silly. Hardly ideal but I'm happy with the cowboy approach for this application.

Comment: Most hashable built-ins don't provide any way to mutate them. When defining your own hashable classes, it's mostly impossible to prevent mutation, so all you can do is document the fact that the object should be treated as logically immutable.